# Need help in removing duplicates in my Query

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
SELECT ID, ind, item_cnt, 
    case when ind = 'True' and item_cnt = 0 then 'Cat Z'
    case when ind = 'True' and item_cnt is NULL then 'Cat Z'
    WHEN  item_cnt between 1 and 4 then 'Cat Y'
    WHEN  item_cnt >=  5 then 'Cat X' 
    when ind= 'False' AND item_cnt IS NULL then 'NE' 
    when Sign_In_E10 = 'False' AND ORDER_COUNT=0 then 'NE' END  
    END as status
FROM (
    select ID, ind, min(item_cnt_check) AS item_cnt
    FROM dbname.schema_name.tbl_name_1 A
    JOIN dbname.schema_name.tbl_name_2 B
        ON B.id_col = A.id_col
    JOIN dbname.schema_name.tbl_name_3 C
        ON C.id_col = B.id_col
    WHERE B.date_created  = '2022-24-01'
        AND flag_column = '0'
        AND src NOT IN ('0','1','2','3')
        AND ID='237362314577'
    group by ID,ind
) A;
```

```
SELECT visit_ID, Sign_In_E10, ORDER_COUNT, 
    case when Sign_In_E10 = 'True' and ORDER_COUNT = 0 then 'BNC'
     when Sign_In_E10 = 'True' and ORDER_COUNT IS NULL then 'BNC'
    WHEN  ORDER_COUNT between 1 and 4 then 'Newly Acquired'
    WHEN  ORDER_COUNT >=  5 then 'Existing'
```

I need help in removing the duplicate records. When I run the above query, I'm getting duplicate values.Need help in removing duplicates please.

| Row | ID | IND | ITEM_CNT | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23736231457 | TRUE | NULL | Cat Z |
| 2 | 237362314577 | FALSE | 2 | Cat Y |

For 1 ID, I should get only one record. Can you provide how to write a query such that it would display unique ID? Can I use MAX aggregate function and filter the latest records?

Comment: can you please specify what you are referring by "duplicate" and attach some screenshots and sample data

Comment: Usually this would indicate your tables are related via a many to one/many. A "duplicate" could be displayed if the selected columns do not include the columns on the many table side that were the reason for the collection to begin with. Example: Product and product colors could be a one to many and if you join them but do not select the color column then it would appear you have duplicate data.

Comment: Seeing as we have no idea what type of data you have or your schema structure etc we can only speculate at best. You could update the question and include an [mcve] if you need additional help.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is almost always a red flag. `DISTINCT` in an aggregating subquery makes no sense.

Comment: I will add the results in sometime. Please check and update. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I just added the result. Could you please guide me how to proceed further. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can use the  ROW_NUMBER windows function in snowflake and pick up WHERE row_num = 1.https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/row_number.html